# Displaying HTML pages in an ASP.Net MVC Web App

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a simple MVC site but I need to add in some static HTML pages, I have tried to add an IgnoreRoute in for .html files but this didn't work.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365001/asp-net-mvc-how-to-use-static-html-pages-in-mvc-applications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.html/{*pathInfo}"); worked for me. And place it before all other route definitions in your global.asax.